# Facebook for USSD

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, ussd

I am currently trying to build a USSD service using Facebook API's.

However, Facebook has upgraded to v2.0 API's and now it requires Facebook permissions in order to use some features.

So firstly, what should i create the type of my new app in Facebook developer site( there is not USSD type, the types available are iOS, Android, Facebook Canvas and Website)?

And how can i grant access to the features that i will use(manage_notifications,publish_actions,read_requests,read_stream,status_update)?

Comment: Not possible. There is no way for the user to login

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).